# Google event snippet doesn't show buy link

Tags: google-search, google-search-console, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I have a web page to sell movie theatre tickets and I added Json LD metadata to publish events.

Google search console is showing events correctly and I can see the snippet when searching for my movie theatre.

However the event time doesn't have the link to buy tickets. I read "offer" element is required, and this is what I have done. Furthermore, I checked this FAQ: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/event#site-not-showing-for-purchase-tickets and I also tried to send more than one times a re-evaluation form (https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeoRYNFmYPdoj81jJAl9wS_0RsU-y8b9rVjHgZ1hZzCFXJ8hw/viewform?pli=1).

This is an example: https://www.google.com/search?q=programmazione+impero+bra
As you can see there is not buy link.
[image]

This is an example of my buy page with metadata: https://ticket.cinebot.it/impero/evento/1482 (it will expire in few days, find more events here: https://ticket.cinebot.it/impero)

Can someone tell me why there is no buy link?

How can I understand is these snippet is truly linked to my page and not somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my website and Google removed the JSON data. I did not know how to solve it, but a friend suggest that I remove the SEO Plugin after removing the site again in Google Gallery.

If you have any SEO plugins, deactivate them for some days; maybe this will solve you problem.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, unfortunately this is not a CMS and I don't have any plugin.